# Fetch other after match other string using regex in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, regex, function, datatable

hi guys i have to create a function in which i have to call a regex so that when  that regex is being call it match a string but store other string in the datatable for example i have string  like this

```
string hello=@"RP/NYC1S21DD/NYC1S21DD            WS/SU   6MAY13/0509Z   **Y33ORG**                
NYC1S21DD/80948W/6MAY13                                                        
1.CORTES RIVERA/MARIA(ADT)   2.ROMERO VEGA/LISA(ADT)                         
3.SHIRA/MARK C(ADT)   4.SHIRA ROMERO/MARINA E(ADT)                           
5.SHIRA ROMERO/MONIQUE A(ADT)   6.SHIRA ROMERO/DYLAN M(CHD)                    
 )>SP1                                                                           
 RP/NYC1S21DD/NYC1S21DD            WS/SU   6MAY13/0509Z   XXXXXX                
 1.CORTES RIVERA/MARIA(ADT)                                                   
 2  UA1162 W 21JUN 5*BQNEWR HK1   150A 545A 21JUN  E  UA/GW176R               
 3  UA1209 W 21JUN 5*EWRLAX HK1   700A 955A 21JUN  E  UA/GW176R               

)>FXR                                                                              
 01 CORTES RI*/MARIA                                                            
 ITINERARY REBOOKED  /// when i found this line i want to fetch PNR number                                                      
 LAST TKT DTE 06MAY13 - SEE ADV PURCHASE";
```

in the above string when i found ITINERARY REBOOKED i want to show PNR number **Y33ORG** in the gridview how can i do that 
Thanks in advance

Comment: now i using (\s[0-9A-Z]{6}\s) regex but it will give me PNR number but i want to first check whether it has itinerary rebooked then only show PNR number in datagridview

Answer (score 1):

Use a look ahead assertion:

```
([*0-9A-Z]{10})(?=(.*ITINERARY.*REBOOKED.*?))
```

A PNR followed by "ITINERARY REBOOKED" text will match this with multiline regex flag ON.

1.. Matching when text present :

http://regexr.com?34pdm

2.. Not matching when text is not present :

http://regexr.com?34pds

Comment: PNR is Y33ORG not **Y33ORG** sry i made a mistake but if i run ur regex for two or three string it didn't match

Comment: You have included '**' in your example string. Even if they are ignored, the regex for PNR will also match 'XXXXXX' since both contain 6 alphanumeric characters. You may edit the first part of this regex to suit it to the PNR number, and this regex will work

Comment: http://gskinner.com/RegExr/?34pdm go to that link it will tell why it is not working

Comment: That link is working, change the text as you want, then click "Share link" and share the link here

Comment: the link i gave it to you will match ticket number mate it not matching PNR number

Comment: i can up vote that answer because it work it your link but it wont work for me for three to four list of array